# Solutions to migrate databases

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration

I'm working in redesign an application. This application has a MySQL database and has approximately 50 tables (there are no relations , there are not standars, etc). We want to migrate to Postgresql with some tables, some tables will not migrate, some will be residing totally and so more changes. My question is : Which techniques are recommend for this task ? Are there any tools for these job? and How can I do these in a efficient way?

Comment: "There are no relations". Er. I assume you mean "there are no foreign key constraints (relationships)"? A "relation" is a table or view.

Comment: As for the rest: What did you already try? Have you read the (many) existing questions on this topic? Looked into ETL tools? What was wrong with what you already found?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your are able to code I'd write a conversion tool which reads from one database and writes into the other. That way you'll be able to do any conversion you like, do additional checks on the data and you could even have the program test the result. Just pick your favorite language. Any tool will still require you to define all the conversions one way or another, you'll still have to test etc. So the overall gain of a special to won't bee that big, and you'll have to learn it first. Assuming it's a one-off it probably simply isn't worth the effort to find a learn a new tool.

If you are planning to do these kind of conversions more often that might change though.